# check for all broken links of type "External Link"

Tags: broken-links

I'm using sitecore9.1.1. 
I need a way to get a list of all items that has a field of type "General Link" that is set to "External Link" and is not working.

(i.e return all broken external links in my sitecore tree).

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Sitecore PowerShell Extensions comes with a Broken Links report which optionally includes external links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess [Sitecore Powershell Extension](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx) is a better way to check the external broken links on a general link field, a sample script can be like below -

```
$startPath = "/sitecore/content/website/home"

function Item-Report($i){
   $t =  $i | Get-ItemField -ReturnType TemplateField  -Name "*" | ForEach-Object{
       if($_.Type -eq "General Link"){
       if($i[$_.Name].contains('linktype="external"')){
           [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$field = $i.Fields[$_.Name]

       $Url = $field.Url

        try{
           $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
           $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()

           # We then get the HTTP code as an integer.
           $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

            If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
              Write-Host "URL is OK! for " $i.Id "and Field" $_.Name
            }
            Else {
              Write-Host "Error or broken link on Item ID" $i.Id "and Field" $_.Name
            }
         }
         catch{
            Write-Host "Error or broken link on Item ID" $i.Id "and Field" $_.Name
         }
       }
    }
  }
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $startPath -Recurse | % { Item-Report $_ }
```